# Find every element's first index in a list

Tags: python

Here is a list `a=[1,1,1,2,4,2,4,32,1,4,35,23,24,23]`

I do this in python:

```
unique_number=list(set(a))
ans=map(lambda x:a.index(x),unique_number)
```

output:

```
<map at 0x2b98b307828>
```

I want to know what's wrong with my code and find an more efficient way to achieve this.

Comment: What if you `print(list(ans))` ?

Comment: @khelwood It returns  `[7, 0, 3, 10, 4, 11, 12]`

Comment: What exactly is your desired output? Also you don't need lambda to get `list(map(a.index,list(set(a))))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1303347/2301450

Comment: If you are trying to get the indexes of the unique values, then @khelwood is right, hence the output. If you are trying to get the Unique value itself, then remove `ans=map(lambda x:a.index(x),unique_number)` and directly print `unique_number`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Handling map function in python2 & python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41090310/handling-map-function-in-python2-python3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid keep re-indexing and building a set first - simply build a `dict` iterating over `a` backwards as the dictionary will only keep the last value for a key (in this case - the earliest appearing index), eg:

```
a=[1,1,1,2,4,2,4,32,1,4,35,23,24,23]

first_index = {v:len(a) - k for k,v in enumerate(reversed(a), 1)}
# {1: 0, 2: 3, 4: 4, 23: 11, 24: 12, 32: 7, 35: 10}
```

This way you're only scanning the sequence once.

Comment: maybe take `len(a)` outside the dict comp

Comment: @Chris_Rands yup... or zip `a` with `range(len(a), -1, -1)` instead of `enumerate`... the idea can be tweaked however :)

Answer (score 2):

This code would work as you expected in Python 2. In Python 3, [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) returns an iterator. You could, e.g., convert it to a list:

```
>>> ans=map(lambda x:a.index(x),unique_number)
>>> list(ans)
[7, 0, 3, 10, 4, 11, 12]
```

Comment: No need for lambda here

Comment: @Chris_Rands this is copied from the OP. I was just explaining why he got the output he got.

Comment: Might be worth noting for future reference that the whole lambda can go when using map... Just `list(map(a.index, set(a))` will do it...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for value in map(lambda x:a.index(x),unique_number):
     print(value)
```

or append this:

```
for var in ans:
     print(var)
```